# SwiftUI Using OR (||) in bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any way to use an OR `||` in a Swift UI binding?

Here's an example:

Class 1:

```swift
@State var loading = false
...
```

Class 2:

```swift
@State var loading = false
...
```

Inside of view:

```swift
@ObservedObject var obj1: Class1
@ObservedObject var obj2: Class2
...
...
...
.pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$obj1.loading || self.$obj2.loading) {
    self.obj1.loadData()
    self.obj2.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use extension like below, but pay attention that in such operators you cannot act with binding '*on set*', instead you have to operate with components only - binding only reacts

```
extension Binding where Value == Bool {

    static func ||(_ lhs: Binding<Bool>, _ rhs: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return Binding<Bool>( get: { lhs.wrappedValue || rhs.wrappedValue }, 
                              set: {_ in })
    }
}
```